# Python/tkinter detección de colisión

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un trabajo en donde el objetivo es hacer un programa de recolección de burbujas(circulos o imagenes de burbujas) haciendo click y generando una figura fractal por cada click, el fractal se tiene que generar a una distancia en la que no se genera encima de la figura anterior(es el mismo fractal), y que la distancia a la que se puede hacer click y generarlo no sea tan larga(esta distancia lo decido yo).Al empezar el programa se generan burbujas(no se pueden generar una encima de otra ), y se genera el fractal en la parte inferior , uno haciendo click crea una linea de figuras hasta llegar a una burbuja, y si la figura toca la burbuja esta desaparece y se suman puntos, las figuras desaparecen y se vuelve a la posicion original a recolectar las burbujas que quedan.
Despues de este cuento de hadas:

Ya puedo generar el fractal(aun sin clicks, solo generarlo una vez):

```
`# curva de dragon
"este programa lo he modificado un poquito de otro"
"http://dept-info.labri.fr/~beurton/Enseignement/Algo/2016-
2017/recursivite.pdf"
"desde pag 15 saque la info"

from tkinter import *
from math import sin, cos, radians

"define la posicion desde donde se genera la curva"
def fpos(x0,y0):
"define como variables globales a x,y ; y toman los valores iniciales"
    global x,y,z,v
    z = x0
    v = y0
    x = x0
    y = y0
"esta funcion sirve para dirigir hace que angulo apuntara la curva"
def fcap(angle0):
"define angle como variable global"
    global angle
    angle = angle0
"esto es lo que hara que se genere la curva"

def av(d):
"llama a las variables x,y que en primera instancia estan en posicion 
inicial"
    global x, y
"x2,y2 son los otros puntos hacia donde se dibjuran las siguientes 
lineas"
    x2 = x + d*cos(angle)
    y2 = y + d*sin(angle)
"dibuja la linea del punto x,y a x2,y2 con grosor 2 y color negro"
    can.create_line(x, y, x2, y2, width=2, fill="black")
"ahora los nuevos valores x,y toman los de x2,y2 para las siguientes 
iteraciones"
    x = x2
    y = y2
"esto define a que angulo se dibujaran las lineas"
def tg(a):
    global angle

    angle -= radians(a)
```

## -------------------------------------------------------------------

```
"define t(que tan grande sera la curva),vz( dirige la direccion de la 
curva)"
"usa la recursividad cambiando las direciones a la que se dibujan las 
lineas"
def dragon(t,vz):
    if t==0:
        av(3)
    else:
        dragon(t-1,1)
        tg(vz*90)
        dragon(t-1,-1)
"llama a todas las funciones principales"
def dessiner():
        fpos(400,650)
        fcap(0)
        dragon(10,1)
```

## -------------------------------------------------------------------

```
"se crea la ventana"
fen = Tk()
"se crea el espacio de dibujo canvas
can = Canvas(fen, bg='white', height=800, width=800)
can.pack()
dessiner()
fen.mainloop()`
```

Lo de las burbujas, hemos decidido probar a puros círculos, ya que si no podemos hacer colisiones ni con figuras, pues con imagenes sera peor creo yo.

Entonces no avanzo porque necesito un sistema de colision, asi sabre el área del fractal, asi podre hacer el codigo de generacion de fractal por clicks, y hacer que desaparezcan las burbujas cuando la figura las toca.

Por cierto(aunque es obvio XD),soy aprendiz de python y este es el trabajo final que solo usa Tkinter como interfaz gráfica y que por cierto no nos han enseñado nada, no dejan usar pygame, ni nada mas, solo librerías(o bibliotecas creo) como math o random, dicho esto.... disculpen por los obvios errores de cualquier tipo que hay en esta publicación.

Se también que esta la funcion bbox, que me regresa una tupla pero si les soy sincero, no se que hacer con esos puntos, al igual con la tupla que me regresa find overlapping, he hecho test , pero no logro nada, o sea no se como funciona, se que bbox, crea como rectángulo aproximado al objeto, y que find overlapping da los objetos(creo) que están cerca?
 Actualizacion:
 Para que me entiendan mas como es el juego dejo esto, las burbujas al generarse aleatoriamente pues no deben quedar una encima de otra, igual que el fractal, por eso se hace como una distancia de que tan lejos y que tan cerca se debe hacer click para generar un nuevo fractal, y creo que eso se comprueba igual como con la colision si no estoy mal.
[image][image]

Comment: Hey brother de casualidad tenes el codigo completo???

Comment: Cual codigo? XD, aun no he terminado nada, cuando termine la detección de colisión subiré aquí ya el código y como lo implemente, pero como dije, partiré del código que proporcionó  @TuckerDS, pero la del fractal es todo eso que puse anteriormente.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas círculos o puntos la forma más fácil de detectar colisiones es con el cáculo de longitud de un segmento entre dos puntos.

```
def colision(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2):
  distanciaMinima = r1 + r2
  distanciaEntreCentros = math.sqrt(((x2-x1)**2) + ((y2-y1)**2))

  if abs(distanciaEntreCentros) <= abs(distanciaMinima):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Este sería el código mínimo (no detecta valores invádidos) y donde "r" sería el rádio de los círculos, si fuera un punto sería 0, y obviamente x, y serían las coordenadas de los centros de los cículos o del punto.

Si usas otras formas, lo más rápido es inscribir esas formas en un círculo imaginario.

Espero que te sirva ;)

Comment: ooo fijate que creo que eso me soluciona el tema de las burbujas, pues porque son circulos XD, el problema es el fractal que he puesto, no se como implementar lo que me has puesto ha ese fractal, pero igual muchisimas gracias enserio esto me ayuda, de ahi que yo no sepa como implementarlo XD

Comment: De nada!, y bueno, pues en principio y sin saber mucho que te piden se me ocurren 2 cosas, 1 llamar a la funcion de deteccion de colision por casa punto que generes del fractal (antes de dibujarlo), y la segunda inscribir como te dije el fractal en un circulo ficticio una vez terminado. Seguro que habrá fomulas matematicas para hacerlo, pero hasta ahí no llego. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bueno cambie a un fractal mas "facil", y ya logre encerrarlo en un circulo y generarlo por clicks, el problema esque lo puedo crear uno encima de otro, ademas que como explique antes, aparte de que no se puedan generar uno encima de otro tiene que haber una distancia maxima de la anterior figura en donde yo pueda hacer click y poder generar la nueva.

```
from math import*
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
lienzo=Canvas(root, width=1080,height=720)
lienzo.pack()
x=500
y=500
a=x-30
b=y-7
c=x+87
d=y+107

def callback(event):
    global x,y,a,b,c,d
    print ("Click en","x:" + str(event.x),"y:" + str(event.y))
    x=event.x
    y=event.y
    e=x-30
    f=y-7
    g=x+87
    h=y+107

    if f>d:        
        if h<b:
            if c>=a: 
                print("no se puede crear uno encima de otro")

    else:
        a=e
        b=f
        c=g
        d=h
        copo(3)
        circulo()
def copo(n):

    x_ver1=x
    y_ver1=y
    x_ver2=x
    y_ver2=y+100
    x_ver3=x+87
    y_ver3=y+50





    curva(x_ver1,y_ver1,x_ver2,y_ver2,n)
    curva(x_ver2,y_ver2,x_ver3,y_ver3,n)
    curva(x_ver3,y_ver3,x_ver1,y_ver1,n)
    curva(x_ver1,y_ver1,x_ver2,y_ver2,n)





    return
 def curva(xi,yi,xf,yf,n):
    if n==0:
        lienzo.create_line(xi,yi,xf,yf)

    elif n>0:
        x1=xi+(xf-xi)/3
        y1=yi+(yf-yi)/3

        x3=(2*xf+xi)/3
        y3=(2*yf+yi)/3

        x2=x1+(x3-x1)*cos(pi/3)-(y3-y1)*sin(pi/3)
        y2=y1+(y3-y1)*cos(pi/3)+(x3-x1)*sin(pi/3)

        curva(xi,yi,x1,y1,n-1)
        curva(x1,y1,x2,y2,n-1)
        curva(x2,y2,x3,y3,n-1)
        curva(x3,y3,xf,yf,n-1)
        return
def circulo():
     lienzo.create_oval(a,b,c,d)
     return
copo(3)
circulo()
root.bind('<Button-1>',callback)`
```